# Electron.js Error "require" is not defined in <script> tag of index.html

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

This is NOT a duplicate of previous questions with similar title. Please read the content before you attempt to flag it as duplicate. It is just difficult to describe the problem and distinguish it from previous problems in a one sentence title.  Thank you.

I have a very simple index.html and I want to use node.js API to read a file

```
<body>
<h1>Hello World!</h1>
We are using node <script>document.write(process.versions.node)</script>,
Chrome <script>document.write(process.versions.chrome)</script>,
and Electron <script>document.write(process.versions.electron)</script>.

<!-- Jquery JS-->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="vendor/bootstrap-4.1/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="vendor/bootstrap-4.1/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<script>
    var fs = require('fs');

    fs.readFile('my-file.txt', 'utf8', function(err, data) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(data);
    });
</script>
</body>
```

When I run 'npm start' , I get an error

> Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
> at index.html:49

Since I read some previous questions I made sure that in main.js (the main process) I set nodeIntegration to true.

```
webPreferences: {
    nodeIntegration: true
}
```

Where am I doing wrong? I just want to achieve the really simple goal of using embedded javascript in  tag in an html to read a file, that's it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You shoud also set contextIsolation to false, or choose to use preload.js

> ```
>  new BrowserWindow({
>     webPreferences: {
>       nodeIntegration: true,
>       contextIsolation: false
>     }
>   });
> ```

You can learn more from here: https://www.electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/context-isolation